# Show that bilinear form is coercive

Tags: boundary-value-problem, poissons-equation

I have got the following problem. Let $G$ be bounded and connected. For $u,v \in H^1(G)$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ define $B(u,v) := \langle \nabla u, \nabla v \rangle$ and $B_{\lambda}(u,v) := \langle \nabla u, \nabla v \rangle - \lambda \langle u , v \rangle$ where $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ is the $L^2(G)$ dot product. Define $D(A) := \lbrace u \in H^1(G) \vert \exists f \in L^2(G) : \forall v \in H^1(G):B(v,u) = \langle v,f \rangle \rbrace$.

I showed already that the set $D(A)$ implies the Neumann boundary conditions $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \vec{n}} = 0$ for the Poisson Equation $\triangle u = f$.

and I showed

For $u \in D(A)$ exists exactly one $f_u \in L^2(G)$ such that $\forall v \in H^1(G) : B(u,v) = \langle v,f_u \rangle$.

Now I'm stuck at the following

I need to show that

1. $\forall \lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ with $Re(\lambda) < 0$: $B_{\lambda}$ is coercive.
2. For all $0 \neq \lambda \in i \mathbb{R}$: $\vert B_{\lambda} (u,u) \vert \geq \alpha \Vert u \Vert_{H^1}$ for $\alpha > 0$.

We defined coercive in this context as $Re(B(u,u)) \geq p \Vert u \Vert_{H^1}^2$ for $p > 0$.

Any tip would be great.

Comment: Why do you call the set $D(A)$ not $D(B)$? Doesn't it stand for the domain?

Comment: Is $G$ a subset of $\mathbb R^d$?

Comment: Is it correct that for $u \in H^1(G)$ we have \begin{align*}
\Re(B_{\lambda}(u, u))
& = \Re(\| \nabla u \|_{L^2} - \lambda \| u \|_{L^2})
= \| \nabla u \|_{L^2} - \underbrace{\Re(\lambda)}_{< 0} \| u \|_{L^2} \\
& = \underbrace{\| \nabla u \|_{L^2}}_{\ge 0} + \underbrace{(- \Re(\lambda))}_{> 0} \underbrace{\| u \|_{L^2}}_{\ge 0}
\ge p ( \| \nabla u \|_{L^2} + \| u \|_{L^2})
\end{align*}
for $$p = \begin{cases} - \Re(\lambda), & \text{if } \Re(\lambda) \ge 1, \\ - \frac{1}{\Re(\lambda)}, & \text{if } \Re(\lambda) < 1. \end{cases}$$

Comment: And we should also have
$$
| B_{\lambda}(u, u) |^2
\ge \Im(B_{\lambda}(u, u))^2
= (\| \nabla u \|_{L^2} + \Im(\lambda) \| u \|_{L^2})^2
$$
If $\Im(\lambda) < 0$, we have $| B_{\lambda}(u, u) |^2 \ge C \| u \|_{H^1}^2$ by the first part. 
If $\Im(\lambda) > 0$, we should be able to find a $C$ like in part (a), no?

Comment: No it should be D(A) in this exercise the operator A was not given. The task was to determine the boundary conditions only using the domain of A and the associated form B.

Comment: Your answers are all correct. But the question had the wrong definition for coercive. We should have used  $Re(B(u,u)) \leq p \Vert u \Vert^{2}_{H^1} - d \Vert u \Vert^{2}_{L^2}$ for $p,d > 0$. I can post the answer to this if you like

Comment: I would like that!